# Select value based on dimension in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have multiple binary segmentation masks. Combined they result in a 3D array. If you sum up a pixel in the 3rd dimension it should add up to `1`, i.e. a pixel should have only one `1` throughout its 3rd dimension:

```py
[[0, 0],
 [1, 0]],

[[1, 1],
 [0, 1]]
```

Unfortunately this condition is not given for my 3D array:

```py
[[0, 0],
 [1, 1]],

[[1, 0],
 [1, 0]],

[[1, 1],
 [1, 0]]
```

As seen the value at `2,1` is equal in all three channels.

I would like to set the value in lower channels to `0` if in a higher channel a `1` exists.
How could I achieve that the array in the second example results to this:

```py
[[0, 0],
 [0, 1]],

[[0, 0],
 [0, 0]],

[[1, 1],
 [1, 0]]
```

Comment: isn't the second to last line in your last code block wrong? its `[1, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

That's rather easy using [Numpy's advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
import numpy as np

img = np.array([[[0, 0],
                 [1, 1]],
                [[1, 0],
                 [1, 0]],
                [[1, 1],
                 [1, 0]]])

print(img)

print(np.sum(img, axis=2))

# check for ones in the first position in the third axis  
# and get a mask for boolean indexing  
mask = img[:, :, 0] == 1

print(mask)
img_2 = img.copy()

# apply the mask to the second element in the third axis
# and set the values to zero there IF there was a one
# in the other place: when the boolean mask is True
img_2[:,:,1][mask] = 0 

print(img_2)

print(np.sum(img_2, axis=2))
```